# How to generate a query to db if several "where" are added in the loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a method with two incoming arrays. The first array $columns[] contains columns names. The second one $filters[] contains search filters. How can I sort through all the values of these columns using only one search query? I can not figure out how this is done through "Eloquent".
I want generate something like this:

```
$data::where($columns[0], '=', $filters[0])
            ->where($columns[1], '=', $filters[1])
            ...
            ->where($columns[n], '=', $filters[n])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any loop

```
$query = new Model;
$count = count($columns);
for($i=0;$<$count;$i++){
   $query->where($columns[$i], '=', $filters[$i]);
}
$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: You could replace `$count = 10;` by `$count = sizeof($columns);`

Comment: @ValdoRaya:  good, But my intention was to share loop to add where clause.

Comment: @user2486. Looks like this is what I need. And how can I do the same with "Update"?

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($whereColumns); $i++){
            $query->where($whereColumns[$i], '=', $whereFilters[$i]);
            }
            for($i=0; $i<count($updateColumns); $i++){
                $query->update($updateColumns[$i] => $updateFilters[$i]);
            }
            $result = $query->get();

Comment: You need to make array or rows inside loop and update at last

Comment: Try yourself and if you get any problem ask here

Comment: @user2486, could you clarify a bit about "update"? I have an error if I use such code: update($updateColumns[$i] => $updateFilters[$i]);

Comment: DO you want by single or bunch of row ?

Comment: @user2486, any way to update several columns ($updateColumns) and searching by several other columns ($whereColumns) in a single search query.

Comment: Yes it is possible , share in your question or ask another question with 3-4 rows of sample data.

Comment: @user2486, done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479070/how-to-generate-a-query-to-db-if-several-where-and-update-are-added-in-the-l

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $data = new Model::query();
    for($i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++)
    {
       $data->where($columns[$i], $filter([$i]));
    }

  $res =  $data->get();
```

sorry if I got your question wrong