# How to generate a query to db if several “where” and “update” are added in the loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a method with four incoming arrays.

The first two arrays `$whereColumns[]` and `$updateColumns[]` contain columns names.

The third column `$whereFilters[]` contains filters for `where` methods.

And the last one `$updateFilters[]` contains values for updating.

How can I generate only one search query with several `where` methods and several updated columns? Now I know only how create a query with several `where` methods in a loop.

```php
for($i=0; $<count($whereColumns); $i++){
    $query->where($whereColumns[$i], '=', $whereFilters[$i]);
}
$result = $query->get();
```

But how to generate a query with `update` like this (but this doesn't work):

```php
for($i=0; $i<count($updateColumns); $i++){
    $query->update($updateColumns[$i] => $updateFilters[$i]); 
} 
$result = $query->get();
```

Both of these loops should generate one search query in total for updating a table data.

Comment: Found a very short answer:            $where = array_combine($whereColumns, $whereFilters);
            $update = array_combine($updateColumns, $updateFilters);
            $red = $instance::where($where)->update($update);

Comment: What are you expecting to get in your update `$result`?

Comment: You can't run `$query->get()` after you execute `$query->update()`, assuming you are currently operating on an instance of a [query builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) because it would no longer be a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your `$updateColumns` and create an array containing all columns and values like this: 
`$updateArray = [$column[0] => $value[0], $column[1] => $value[1]];`

Then you can put this whole array into the query

`$query->update($updateArray);`